# ELI5 how to install AEON on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: aeon, source

After the downloading the [tar.gz file from GitHub](https://github.com/aeonix/aeon/releases/tag/v0.9.11.0) to my default downloads folder what do I do next?

The [readme](https://github.com/aeonix/aeon/blob/master/README) below seems to provide general instructions for compiling from master but is not specific for installing the latest release I downloaded above.

### Compiling AEON

> On Unix and Linux:
>
> Dependencies: GCC 4.7.3 or later, CMake 2.8.6 or later, and Boost 1.53 or later (except 1.54).
>
> - To build, change to the root of the source code directory, and run 'make'.
> - The resulting executables can be found in build/release/src.

When I extract the tar.gz file I do not see the executable file (aeond or aeon-wallet-cli) like I would when performing the same process for a Monero release. Please provide me with step by step commands to install AEON starting with the assumption that I have downloaded to tar.gz file for the v0.9.11.0 AEON release

Comment: Compiling means that there is no executable yet. Thus, you have to compile it. From the instruction, you have to extract it then change the directory to extracted files. After that just run make and it should create the executable files. Lastly, double check for error messages because  If there are errors it won't is compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assumes that your default downloads folder is called *Downloads* and that it's a subdirectory of your home directory, that the aeon source code archive that you downloaded is called *aeon-0.9.11.tar.gz* and that it get unpacked as an *aeon-0.9.11* directory. You'll have to adjust the instructions if the names of your files or directories differ.

Open a command-line terminal and enter the following four commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
gzip -cd aeon-0.9.11.tar.gz | tar xvf -
cd aeon-0.9.11
make
```

If you've already got all necessary dependencies installed, the above will just work. But if not, you'll need to install whatever's missing using whatever package manager Ubuntu provides. You've probably already got *make* — find out (from your terminal) by entering `make --version`, and if you've already got cmake, then `cmake --version` will tell you the version. The GCC 4.7.3 dependency means the C++ compiler, so check the version by entering `g++ --version`. If you have the boost headers installed, you can perhaps list them with `ls /usr/include/boost`, and you should be able to list the boost libaries with `ls /usr/lib|grep boost`: this may give you a clue as to which boost version you've got (for instance, I've got version 1.56, and that last comamnd tells me that I have various files with names similar to *libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0*.

If the build works, you will end up with *aeond*, *simplewallet*, *simpleminer* and *connectivity_tool* in the folder *~/Downloads/aeon-0.9.11/build/release/src* (note that “*~*” is a quick way of referring to your home directory). Try entering `ls -l ~/Downloads/aeon-0.9.11/build/release/src` for a detailed listing.