# Compiling the Monero GUI from source for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monero-wallet-gui

Executable can't be found  in the build/release/bin folder? I might be doing something wrong, had no errors while compiling the monero-gui.

I'm new to ubuntu. I went to the https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/blob/master/README.md and followed the instructions to compile the monero-gui. When it finished I went to build/release/bin folder and there is no executable.

Found this answers and haven't been able to make it work.

[ELI5 how to install AEON on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4038/eli5-how-to-install-aeon-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

[Compile from source](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4080/compile-from-source)

I don't have much knowledge about what is compiling from source, building dependencies, or installing from a package. This is how the monero-gui repository looks like.

[image]

If I go to the build/release/bin there is only the translations folder, no executable for the monero-gui. 
There is no monerod, no monero-blockchain-export, etc. anywhere. I downloaded the  monero-gui-v0.11.1.0 for linux-64bit from https://getmonero.org/downloads/, but I'm not sure if I have to do anything with it, paste it in the monero-gui folder or what??..

[image]

[image]

If I did something wrong or I'm missing something, can anyone help? Thank you for your patience. :)

Comment: Did you run `./build.sh`? Also, did you follow the instructions here: https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui#compiling-the-monero-gui-from-source

Comment: Hi, yes I did the exact same instructions and also did run ./build.sh. Thought I might had an error and didn't notice and did run ./build.sh again and got this message error in terminal. /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwallet_merged
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lepee
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -leasylogging
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lreadline
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:274: recipe for target 'release/bin/monero-wallet-gui' failed
make: *** [release/bin/monero-wallet-gui] Error 1

Comment: It might be related to the `monero` repository (which currently doesn't build without some patches). Could you try to compile the monero repository and see if that fails? If so, it's likely the reason the GUI build fails.

Comment: hi, I was not able to build from the monero repository. Followed this: Install the dependencies, Build instructions/Monero uses the CMake build system and a top-level Makefile that invokes cmake commands as needed. [Makefile](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/Makefile). Opened terminal started and got this error.  mkdir -p build/debug; cd build/debug && cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../..
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/siddha" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Comment: I also did a installation package using snap and was able to list snap packages, I see the monero 0.11.1-1 installed but I'm not able to open, or either find monero anywhere....went to [snapcraft](https://docs.snapcraft.io/core/usage) to see how to open snap packages, but was not able to open monero.